# How to disable mouse capture in embed swf object?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, flash

While scrolling, when the cursor is over the embed flash object, scrolling stops and does not continue until the cursor is outside of the object, whether it is possible as it is to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

first set your wmode to transparent in embedding code.
`<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />`

then place a div to the entire surface of your swf. This should work fine.